# Partial implicit differentiation question help - Solved

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

I doing some multivariable calculus work and was struggling with the following question.

Given:
$$
e^{7z} = xyz
$$
The task is to compute the partial derivatives dz/dx and dz/dy using implicit differentiation.
My solution is now as follows:
$$
(dz/dx) 7e^{7z} = yz + (dz/dx)xy
$$
And so,
$$
(dz/dx) (7e^{7z}-xy) = yz
$$
Therefore correct answer is,
$$
\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{yz}{(7e^{7z}-xy)}
$$

Comment: you need to think of $z = z(x,y)$ for this problem since apparently the problem assumes you should take $x,y$ as the independent variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are three variables so it will be differentiated by product rule i.e.
$\frac{dz}{dx}7e^{7z}= yz+ \frac{dy}{dx}xz+ \frac{dz}{dx}xy$

Comment: precisely the problem. Both $z$ and $x$ are functions of $x$.